# Powershell alter Backup Scripts for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to assist my System Administrator by writing a Powershell script that takes parameters and will translate that into a backup script for several SQL Server databases that need to be backed up before and after our deployments.

I would ideally like to allow him to input these params:

```
@Database = 'Genesis'
@BackupName = 'Genesis_backup'
@BackupDate = '2016_01_20'
@BackupDateTime = '2016_01_20_01340_3181013'
@Location = 'E:\SQLBackup\TEST'
```

So if this is the backup string

```
BACKUP DATABASE [@Database] TO  DISK = N'E:\SQLBackup\TEST - 20160120\Genesis_backup_2016_01_20_01340_3181013.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Genesis_backup_2016_01_20_01340_3181013', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
GO
```

I would like Powershell to build it to look like

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Genesis] TO  DISK = N'@Location - @BackupDate\@BackupName_@BackupDateTime.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'@BackupName_@BackupDateTime', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
GO
```

How would I start something like this out? What functions would you recommend I use for this? Also how do I parse out the locations dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways: use straight TSQL (favored by the DBA crowd) or use Sql Server's SMO API (more Powershell-ish, emulates SSMS wizards). As a lot of DBA people are more familiar with TSQL, it's easier to get help with the TSQL path.

Instead of rolling your own solution, a popular approach is to use Ola Hallengren's [maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/) which includes tried and true backup procedures. Ola's solution uses Sql Server Agent jobs for scheduling, so Sql Express needs to use, say, Task Scheduler. With Ola's stuff, just create additional an agent job which backs up the databases you want. Agent jobs can be started by executing [`sp_start_job`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) sproc. This can be done with, say, sqlcmd or Powershell's [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just want to build some strings out. Keep it simple. He's not a DBA...and I don't want to run it from outside SSMS. I just want him to be able to open SSMS and plop the results of my script in there. updated question to show what I've done thus far.